# All content deleted when WP was reinstalled in another machine

Tags: php, installation

I had a laptop which I sold a week ago. Today I got my new one, I installed Filezilla and put my credentials in it, clicked on Quick Connect and I saw some files came up, even though I checked the wp-content folder and I can’t see the theme I put there the first time, which I guess means that those folders doesn’t contain the same content I put there the first time when I installed WP in my first machine. When I reinstalled WP I put all of the credentials it asked me.

Now, my page doesn’t have anything but the initial WP content: http://lunatixcr.com/

What can I do in order to recover my last state of the page?

***Note: I am tagging PHP here because tons of PHP programmers has worked with WP so it can be helpful.***

**UPDATE**

I have seen a .zip file within `public_html` folder with the name of `wp-config.zip`, what is that? look https://i.stack.imgur.com/alADr.jpg

Comment: did you change your wp-config?  Is your database still intact?  That could have been overwritten.  check it.  if it's gone wp will try to go into install mode.  You'll need to manually get one (from an old install) and make sure the credentials are for your database.  This includes the db table prefix

Comment: @rudtek nope, I didn't change anything. I only removed the installation from my old computer and installed WP in my new one. I have seen a .zip file within `public_html` folder with the name of `wp-config.zip`, what is that? look http://imgur.com/J3ReCjz

Comment: ha.  that's what you need.  unzip it.

Comment: @rudtek awesome, and then?

Comment: i saw your image from below.  Can you post all contents in the directory and in the wp-config.zip? i'll tell you what might work once i know what you have.  in the meantime also confirm that the settings are correct in the wp-config file if it is in that wp-config.zip

Answer (score 0):

Within Filezilla, check to see if your custom theme folder appears in the `wp-content` of your remote host. If yes, you may simply need to log in to your remote `/wp-admin` and ensure that it is active.

If it's not there, check with your remote host.  They may have a backup of your remote `wp-content` and database.

Comment: is this actually true?  Ftp will replace files that are uploaded but leave others alone.  So your wp-content folder files and uploads should remain.  That's how i thought it worked.

Comment: Dang! You're right.  Looks like merging is Filezilla's default behavior on folder uploads.

Comment: I have seen a .zip file within `public_html` folder with the name of `wp-config.zip`, what is that? look http://imgur.com/J3ReCjz